# Center a ul within a div (within a div) which itself is centered on the page

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm attempting to center my CSS menu but I'm having issues, basically I'd like it to be in the center of my `content` div. Currently it's displaying from the left. Does anyone know what I would have to add to achieve what I want? Below is my code.

My index.html

```
<head>

<meta content="en-ie" http-equiv="Content-Language" />

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

 <title>Title</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="contain">

    <div id="header">

        <p><img alt="" height="67" src="header.png" width="431" /><br />
        </p>
    </div>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.free-css.com/"><span>Item 1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.free-css.com/"><span>Item 2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.free-css.com/"><span>Item 3</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">


</div>

<div id="footer" style="width: 93px; height: 12px">

</div>

 </body>

</html>
```

My style.css

```
body{
background-color: #292929;

}
  p{
color: white;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
    }

   h2{
color: white;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 18px;
    }

    a:link {
    COLOR: #00CCFF;
    }
   a:visited {
     COLOR: #00CCFF;
   }
   a:hover {
    COLOR: #00CCFF;
     }
  a:active {
   COLOR: #00CCFF;
    }

   /* DIV's */

   #contain {
background-color:#444343;
width: 700px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
opacity: .5;
    }
    #header {
width: 700px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
    }

   #content { 
float: left;
width: 700px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;

    }

    #footer {
color: white;
font-size:10px;
width: 11px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;

}

   #tabs {
float:left;
width:100%;
font-size:93%;
border-bottom:1px solid #292929;
line-height:normal;
}

   #tabs ul {
margin:0;
padding:10px 10px 0 50px;
list-style:none;
text-align: center;
}

    #tabs li {
display:inline;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

   #tabs a {
float:left;
background:url("tableft.gif") no-repeat left top;
margin:0;
padding:0 0 0 4px;
text-decoration:none;
}

   #tabs a span {
float:left;
display:block;
background:url("tabright.gif") no-repeat right top;
padding:5px 15px 4px 6px;
color:#FFF;
}

   /* Commented Backslash Hack hides rule from IE5-Mac \*/
  #tabs a span {float:none;}

  /* End IE5-Mac hack */
  #tabs a:hover span {
color:#FFF;
}

   #tabs a:hover {
background-position:0% -42px;
}

   #tabs a:hover span {
background-position:100% -42px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can set a fixed width for the `#tabs ul` (for example `width:200px;` ) and then you change the `margin:0;` to `margin:0 auto;` for `#tabs ul`

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you need horizontal centering of block of unknown width. I see two approaches:

1. Simple one: you will omit all the fancy markup of your tabs and preserve just inline links in inline LIs and add `display: block;` to your `#tabs ul` rule. No floating, no blocks within menu, just plain inline text. This will work, but will no be much 'styllable'. pastebin.me/58fe73dd82496444fd7e129fc5830b4b
2. Complex one: add extra wrap around your `ul`, so you'll got `#tabs #tabs-in ul li …`

```
    #tabs {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    }

    #tabs-in { 
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    }
    #tabs ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    }
    #tabs li {
    display:block;
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
```

http://pastebin.me/23c1b8a60657962f1d8c8baef2700473 This old "move it half parents width right and then it move half its own width left" trick works quite well. But good luck styling it further and keeping it cross-browser compatible :]